# Copy Rotate and Paste in Multiple Cells

Tags: excel, vba, image, rotation, paste

I am using an Excel VBA function to generate a barcode as image and paste it with rotation in two cells.

Only the first paste is rotated and not the second one.

```vb
Set xObjOLE = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add("BARCODE.BarCodeCtrl.1")
xObjOLE.Object.Style = 7
xObjOLE.Object.Value = "0123456789"
xObjOLE.Width = 120
xObjOLE.Height = 30
xObjOLE.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

Set xRRg = Application.Range("H5")
ActiveSheet.Paste xRRg
With Selection
    .ShapeRange.Rotation = 270
End With

Set xRRg = Application.Range("S5")
ActiveSheet.Paste xRRg
With Selection
    .ShapeRange.Rotation = 270
End With

xObjOLE.Delete
```

Comment: Hi, you are not rotating the copies; you are rotating the original image. Your code never selects the new images.

Answer (score 0):

my first suggestion is rotating the original image, then paste it in two places.

The alternative is selecting the copies, but for that I need to know if you have other images in the file.

**First solution**

To make it reproducible I am adding only the code for the "Set" chunk. Given that, you need to *select an image first*, then run my code.

```
Sub MacroCopy()
    'Rotate first
    Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = 270
    Selection.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture


    Set xRRg = Application.Range("H5")
    ActiveSheet.Paste xRRg
    
    Set xRRg = Application.Range("S5")
    ActiveSheet.Paste xRRg
    
    'If you need to rotate back to zero
    Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = 0

End Sub
```

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Hi Fernando, 
I am using the below code but getting 
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method

debugger point to --> Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = 270

Comment: Please note that I am generating the barcode using OLEObjects and then copying it as picture within the code (not by manually selecting and copying in the excel sheet). I need to rotate this picture and copy this at two places. The excel file might contain other static images.